# why is my animations not working?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiview

I have a little blue circle that fades in and out to two different locations until the user touches the screen. Then I want the circle to fade out in the position it is at.

```
- (void)fadePowerUpOut {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{//the power up will stay in its position until after 2 seconds it will fade out which is because of the delay
        self.powerUp.alpha=0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {//I put if finished here because i don't want this method to be ran if the user touches the screen within the 2 second delay
            if (self.powerUp.frame.origin.x==self.rectPowerUp.origin.x) {//if its in the first location go to the second
                self.powerUp.frame=self.rectPowerUp2;

            }else{//if its in the second location go to the first 
                self.powerUp.frame=self.rectPowerUp;
            }
            [self fadePowerUpIn];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)fadePowerUpIn {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.powerUp.alpha=1;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (finished) {
              [self FadePowerUpOut];
        }   
    }];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

     [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(){ self.powerUp.alpha=0;} completion:^(BOOL completion){
  }];
}
```

What is happening is, when the user touches the screen the circle just does not fade out, but only fades out after the 2 seconds (the delay I put on the fadePowerUpOut method).

Comment: Why dont you try setting the delay to zero in both cases and when calling `[self FadePowerUpOut];` try it as `[self performSelector:@selector(FadePowerUpOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ACB indicated the first thing to do is set the Delay to zero. To be able to start the
delayed fadeout I would suggest using a timer.